# How to compile FFT library with NDK for JNI?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

So essentially, I wish to be able to use an fft library like fftw or kissfft to be able to do fft and ifft operations on arrays in the android native code. Using JNI before, writing a .c, a .h, and an Android.mk file allowed me to call simple c methods from java. I've tried to place the right .c and .h files into the jni folder and call ndk-build, but it doesn't work that way. I have to compile it first, and many examples I've found require some kind of make file that I'm not sure how to write either. Would I just compile with gcc into the jni directory?

I'm trying to use kissfft as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must compile the library for Android. You can do it in ADT by "add native support", it will run `ndk-build` automatically for you.

*[Here](https://github.com/ejotado/libgdx/tree/master/extensions/gdx-audio/jni/kissfft)* is an example of the **Android.mk** file that allows to use **kissfft** in an Android project.